# How to remove all URLs based on keywords in the DIV tags

Tags: php, jquery

How to remove specific URLs in DIV tags that are filtered from certain keywords. Suppose I have a text like this:

```
<div class="target">
https://my-site.com/test1_good.html
https://my-site.com/test1_fake.html
https://my-site.com/test2_good.html
https://my-site.com/test2_fake.html
https://my-site.com/test3_good.html
https://my-site.com/test3_fake.html
</div>
```

Here I want all URLs containing the keyword `"_good.html"` so the result becomes:

```
<div class="target">
https://my-site.com/test1_good.html
https://my-site.com/test2_good.html
https://my-site.com/test3_good.html
</div>
```

Can this be done? It does not matter whether to use Javascript, jQuery, or PHP.
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would depend on how you originally output the urls. If you are using PHP and outputting each in a loop, you can use `preg_match()`, otherwise you can use JavaScript using a match like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fetch the urls
    var getCont =   $('.target').text();
    // Create storage
    var getGood =   [];
    // Loop the urls
    $.each(getCont.split('\n'),function(k,v) {
        // If contains the string, save to storage
        if(v.match(/_good/i))
            getGood.push(v);
    });
    // Tell us about it...
    console.log(getGood);
});
</script>
```

In the console, gives you this:

```
[
 "https://my-site.com/test1_good.html",
 "https://my-site.com/test2_good.html",
 "https://my-site.com/test3_good.html"
]
```